# How to right-align signatures on newlfm

Tags: letters, newlfm

I'm trying to use the newlfm class to write a letter, but I've run into this problem.

It's customary in some places to have the signature aligned on the right side, as on stdletter, but everything before that *including the closing line* on the left. So far it has been impossible to do that with newlfm.

```
\documentclass[stdletter]{newlfm}
\closeline{This should be left-aligned}
\namefrom{This should be right-aligned}
\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}
\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

Is there any way to achieve that on this class?

Comment: You mean to have "Best wishes" on the left, but then "John Wickerson" on the right? Where would I sign it, above my name or below the "Best wishes"?

Comment: You would sign right above your name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITED for better solution.  Based on what I learned from my earlier post, I realized that if both the `\closeline` and `\namefrom` were being stuffed into the same box, then I could force the box width to be `\textwidth` without modifying the underlying class.  I do this by putting the `\namefrom` into a box of width `\textwidth`, and just make sure it is right aligned.

```
\documentclass[stdletter]{newlfm}
\closeline{This should be left-aligned}
\namefrom{\makebox[\textwidth][r]{This should be right-aligned}}
\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}
Testing
\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```